# Script file not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am beating my head against the wall on this. I know Javascript/jQuery well and I can not see the reason why this is not working. I've tried both 2.0.3 and 1.10.2 with the same results.

I'm trying to just do a test to make sure the script file is loaded. I've tried a number of different methods, nothing is working. But when I click the url in the source, it goes to the correct file that has the right code.

This is all I'm trying to do.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   alert('test');
});
```

Which works if I include it in the page between `<script>` tags. But not when referencing it from a `.js` file.

This is how I'm loading it:

```
<script type="text/javscript"
        src="http://localhost/kdev/views/dashboard/js/default.js"></script>
```

Clicking on that url takes me to the correct file with the alert above.

But's not working. What the crap is going on? What did I forget? Do I have a typo?

The entire page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Test</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/kdev/public/css/default.css" />
   <script type="text/javscript" 
           src="http://localhost/kdev/public/js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javscript"
           src="http://localhost/kdev/views/dashboard/js/default.js"></script>
</head>
<body>   
<div id="header">
    header
    <br />
    <a href="http://localhost/kdev/index">Index</a>
    <a href="http://localhost/kdev/help">help</a>
               <a href="http://localhost/kdev/dashboard/logout">logout</a>
        </div>

 <div id="content">
 Dashboard... logged in only    </div>
 <div id="footer">feet</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you had a look in both requests loading the js files?

Comment: `type="text/javscript" ` --> `type="text/javascript" `

Comment: type="text/javscript" ?? ;)

Comment: if using <!DOCTYPE html> , just <script src="file.js"></script> is cool too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this (You missed 'a' char in 'javascript')

```
 <script type="text/javscript"
        src="http://localhost/kdev/views/dashboard/js/default.js"></script>
```

to this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://localhost/kdev/views/dashboard/js/default.js"></script>
```

Comment: ..........jQuery was loading fine. Like I said, the function worked fine in the page. Ty so much. I knew it was something stupid.

Comment: In HTML5, you don't even need the `type` attribute. It's unnecesary and only causes trouble.

Answer (score 0):

My lightbox script file wasn't loeading properly:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/lightbox-plus-jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I then removed `type="text/javascript"` and it loaded perfectly.