# Importing jQuery plugin into Angular 2+ Refused to execute script because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angular

I need to load a JavaScript (jQuery plugin) in an HTML file. But it doesn't seem to be working. This is running on Angular-CLI server (ng serve) Here's the HTML.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Test</title>
  <base href="/">

  <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="./test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

I get this error:

> Refused to execute script from
>   'http://localhost:8080/test.js' because its MIME type
>   ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is
>   enabled.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19214276/), where the solution seems to be correcting the `type` attribute, but that didn't fix it for me. I tried `text/javascript` and `application/javascript`.

What do I need to do here?

EDIT: The network console shows a 404 error for the script. Says the request has no response data available. Content type says `text/html; charset=utf-8`

NOTE: I originally posted this as a more minimal example than my actual code, as I didn't think it had to do with Angular CLI server. That may be the case, so I restored my example to the actual code I have.

Comment: Fix your webserver.

Comment: Because your problem is that your web server is returning HTML and it's almost certainly a routing error but you provide no *relevant* information. Open up devtools, look at the network tab, and check what you actually received (it's probably HTML rather than your script). Questions should have (insofar as is possible) information sufficient to reproduce the error in the question itself.

Comment: I'm giving you the information that I *have*. This is running on Angular dev server (ng serve).

Comment: You're not injecting that script tag manually, right? That's the script tag the Angular dev server is injecting? Did you tell Angular to call it test.js?

Comment: It's not. I added both script tags.

Comment: I had this exact same error the other day. For me it was simply a path issue. I was serving the file from the `public` folder so I corrected the src link to point like this `/path/test.js` and it worked fine for me. To test your script, simply copy that url into your browser and if it returns nothing your path script is incorrect.

Comment: Ah, test.js is a script that you want to exist outside your Angular code?

Comment: @Sam, yes, that it correct.

Comment: @Curious13, that worked, the file loads now. I think the error message from Chrome threw me. It should have just said '404'. Anyhow, now the script is loading, but it's not running the script it contains...

Comment: If the file is loading, the file isn't the issue, it might be an issue with whatever code is inside of your script. I would `console.log` to test to see if your script is executing correctly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try putting your js script in the `src/assets` folder. Then it should be served with correct mime type by the development server

Then reference it like below

```
<script src="/assets/scripts/test.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Rather than including jquery and your script in index.html, you could add the files to the "scripts" properties of `angular-cli.json` (or `angular.json` if using angular 6)

```
"scripts":
 [
      //include jQuery here, e.g. if installed with npm
      "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ,
      "assets/scripts/test.js"
 ]
```

**Note**: Don't forget to restart `ng serve` after modifying the `.angular-cli.json` or `angular.json` files

Comment: Yup, this is how I solved it, based on @Curious13's answer. I should have known. There is probably a duplicate somewhere.

Answer (score 6):

I encountered with the similar issue

[image: issue]

and resolved by a simple change in `index.html` file

```
<base href="./"> // remove dot (.) and your app will execute scripts
```

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting, running an old `Angular` project after a couple of years and it was caused due to `<base href="/">`, changing to `<base href="./">` fixed the error.