# MIME type checking failure when deploying the React App on the server

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, server, web-hosting

I am deploying my React app on a public server but when I open it I just get the blank page.

In order to deploy the app I did:

1) run "npm run build" to minify the code and putting into a build folder
2) replaced the local URL in the new index.html file with the correct server ones.

still, when trying to open the website in the console I get these errors.

[image: error image]

Any ideas?

Comment: can we see how you access these resources in your App? Maybe related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49905882/refused-to-execute-script-because-its-mime-type-text-html-is-not-executable/49913501) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40574159/refused-to-execute-script-strict-mime-type-checking-is-enabled).

Comment: i basically replaced the local URL, which pointed to the original React folder, to the new folder in the server.  src="./public_html/static/js/main.f5239b39.js"

Comment: you changed the minified version of your index html to point script adresses somewhere else on the server ?

Comment: Check if your `<stylesheet>` and `<javascript>` element have the expected `type`

Comment: @Jayffe, yes, I addressed on the server folder which is named public_html, where I stored the applicaton itself

Comment: @v-gael what would would it the expected type be?

Comment: `type="text/javascript"` for your js file, it seems for a reason the type is `text/html`

Comment: shoul I just add type="text/javascript" somewhere in the body of the index.html file?

Comment: in your javascript tag: `<script type="text/javascript"></script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem simply correcting the url.

since I was already accessing the "public" folder thanks to the "./" typing in the beginning of the url, there was no need to type "./public".

Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Just edit webpack config by editing this:

```
     devServer: {
       historyApiFallback: true
          }
```

And also add this to public/index.html:

```
  <base href="/" />
```

Hope this help

Comment: Do you mean the webpack string in the package.json? if not, where? also, do you mean i should enclose every href in the base tag?

Comment: Webpack configuration in webpack.config file and you need to change base tag only in index.html file not every file